# python 2.7 file read and split error

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am trying to read and split values from a file (exon_coordinates.txt) based on value ",". The script I wrote looks like this:

```
input_dna = "input_dna.txt"
file_1 = open (input_dna).read().rstrip("\n")
exon_coordinates = "exon_coordinates.txt"
file_2 = open (exon_coordinates).read().rstrip("\n")

for line in file_2:
    print (line)
    positions = line.split (',')
    print (positions)
    start = int(positions [0])
    stop = int(positions [1])
    exon = file_1 [start:stop]
```

exon_coordinates.txt contains values as follows:

```
0,10
19,27
38,44
```

`input_dna.txt` contains a DNA string as follows:

```
ACTGATCGATTACGTATAGTAGAATTCTATCATACATATATATCGATGCGTTCATCTGATCGA
```

However, when I print positions, the output is as follows:

```
0
['0']
,
['', '']
1
['1']
0
['0']

['\n']
1
['1']
9
['9']
,
['', '']
2
['2']
7
['7']

['\n']
3
['3']
8
['8']
,
['', '']
4
['4']
4
['4']
```

Am I going wrong in script or something is wrong in the exon_coordinates.txt file that I created?
I am a biologist with no prior experience in any sort of scripting. Mine might be a very basic problem, but I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed

Comment: In `for line in file_2:`, you are going through the individual characters of the first file.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing strings (the result of 'read') with lists of strings (what you expect from `for line in file_2`, i think)
Maybe this is how you mean to read file_2:

```
with open (exon_coordinates) as file_2:
    for line in file_2:
        positions = line.strip().split(',')
```

Comment: That is very helpful. Thanks. but with that, I will have output as ['0', '10\n']
['19', '27\n']
['38', '44\n']
['\n'] . How should I replace \n from "27\n" from list, unless I do it individually which will make my script long...

Comment: '\n' is a type of whitespace (a newline), python has the handy 'strip' function on strings. Strip removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, and returns a copy of the string.